# Should I keep my EF DBContext object inside its own module, then get it by DI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

I'm currently working with data back and forth from SQL server to my C# WPF app. I'm using prism and Entity Framework to grab my DBContext (using database-first generation if that matters). I have a growing project where I'm going to be connected to this Server through many different screens from different projects at once.

Initially, I simply created a new DBContext object for each ViewModel, but I had a sense that wasn't the correct thing to do from reading online about different instances of context not knowing about changes to eachother.

Now, I'm using DI to bring in a static instance of this same DBContext into any screen's ViewModel that requests it's interface in their constructor. I think it's a pretty simple change, but I don't know if I can say for sure it's better this way.

With the example below, is this an acceptable method to share a common DBContext object generated by Entity Framework? If not, how can I change or better it? Thanks!

```
public interface ICommonContext
{
    ServerEntities Context { get; }
}

public class CommonContext : IModule, ICommonContext
{
  private static ServerEntities _context;
  public ServerEntities Context
  {
    get {  return _context; }
  }

  public void Initialize() {  _context = new ServerEntities(); }
}

/// When used in a VM ///
private ServerEntities _model;

public SomeViewModel(ICommonContext cc){
  _model = cc.Context;
}
//////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **essentially** what we do. I've actually had a PAIN of a time dealing with EF (more so TFS and branching), primarily because we have different regions that have different version of the database. Therefore, the EF model could essentially be changed in each version. Using DI, you can pass in any class that implements the interfaces you define. This is beneficial especially if you decide to write test cases and such.

Long story short, DI is definitely the way to go. I'd even take it a step further and decouple your DbContext from your forms and use something like a repository that you inject into your form. That way, your forms NEVER have to know about your DbContext or where the data is even coming from. This will help if your project ever gets bigger, or you have multiple sources, or for instance if you decide to scrap EF and do something else, etc.

See Gert's answer though about using a Static context. He brings up a valid point. My answer is geared towards building a case for DI. Definitely be cautious going down the static context route. [Check this article.](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management)

Comment: Yeah, you brought up a good point. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a static context is evil. Don't do it.

But in a rich client application like WPF, it's a fairly common pattern to have a context per window instance, which boils down to instance per view model. So just register your context in your DI container with an instance life cycle and inject it into your view models by constructor injection.

Which means: remove your class `CommonContext`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about the cons of using a static context. I saw DI and got giggity.